# Get, "cannot cast 'Field' to 'Field' type (same class)" when trying to Append an object in vb6 from C# library using COM-interop

Tags: c#, com, vb6, com-interop

I have a C# library that is used by legacy vb6 code.  This works really well for most everything except I'm running into an issue appending an object.

In part I'm attempting to emulate some of the access db function calls and redirect them to a different db solution.  But that isn't very relevant to the issue I'm running into, just some background.

I have another object and class very similar to this one; does the same thing too with an Append.  The code is only different in that it's not an "object" that is used but a fixed type.  I tried doing it this way as generics are not supported in the COM standard.

Any ideas or help would be very helpful.

### In vb6

```
Dim fld As Field
Set fld = new Field
NewTd.Fields.Append fld     'gives an error that Field can't be cast to type Field.
```

### C#

Field:

```
 [Guid("2515418d-04af-484e-bb3b-fe53a6121f73")]
 [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
 public class Field : IField
 {
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public string Value { get; set; }

     public int Type { get; set; } //private int TypePV;
     // 3 more public ints.


     enum FieldType
     {
         // different field types.
     }

---

 [Guid("fd362bff-da4e-4419-a379-1ed84ff74f1b")]
 public interface IField
 {
        string Name { get; set; }
        string Value { get; set; }
        int Type { get; set; }
        // three more ints.

 }
```

Where Append is defined.

```
[Guid("0cf3c33f-8ca8-4a5b-8382-d1612558fcad")]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
public class FieldsO : IFieldsO
{
    public object obj;
    public FieldsO(object cobj)
    {
        obj = cobj;
    }

    public object this[string param]
    {
        get 
        {
            if (obj.GetType() == typeof(Recordset))
                return ((Recordset)obj)[param];
            if (obj.GetType() == typeof(TableDef))
                return ((TableDef)obj)[param];
            return null;
        }
        set 
        { 
            if (obj.GetType() == typeof(Recordset))
                ((Recordset)obj)[param] = value; 
            if (obj.GetType() == typeof(TableDef))
                ((TableDef)obj)[param] = (IField)value; 
        }
    }

    public void Append(Field io) {
        if (obj.GetType() == typeof(TableDef)) {
            if (!((TableDef)obj)._Fields.ContainsKey(io.Name))
                ((TableDef)obj)._Fields.Add(io.Name, io);
        }
    }

    public int Count() {
        if (obj.GetType() == typeof(Recordset))
            return ((Recordset)obj).dt.Columns.Count;
        if (obj.GetType() == typeof(TableDef))
            return ((TableDef)obj)._Fields.Count;
        return -1;
    }
}

---

 [Guid("fe528160-1505-448e-bb9c-8ccfd9e3643d")]
 public interface IFieldsO
    {
       object this[string param] { get; set; }
       int Count();
       void Append(Field io);
    }
```

Comment: Try to define `Append(Field io)` as `Append(IField io)` instead.

Comment: @SimonMourier I tried that; it came out to be "Unable to cast object of type "Field" to type "IField"

Comment: Are you sure that your VB type `Field` is the same type that you are exporting in your type library. Perhaps there's another `Field` type polluting your namespace

Comment: Please post a Minimal, Reproducible Example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Flydog57 it was namespaced as "MyInterface" (can't actually include the name for silly reasons)... there is no other reference to a Field type anywhere in the code or object viewer.

Comment: You must not declare types like Recordset, TableDef and Field yourself.  They belong to the ADO library, add a reference instead.

Comment: @HansPassant They are my own library; i'm replacing a lot of objects in the ADO library with classes that share naming convention and syntax to reduce code rewrites.  The only similarity is the name, but nothing here is ADO

Comment: If that were true then it would be your C# code that generated the exception.  Since you'd know about it, the logical conclusion is that the VB6 project is still using ADO instead of your library.

Comment: @HansPassant the C# portion does not generate the exception.  I ran the same vb6 code equivalent in C# and it didn't complain at all.  I've completely removed all ADO libraries and hooks from this machine a few weeks ago while testing other portions of the code.  No references or components are still around.

Comment: You can't remove ADO, it is integral to the OS install with no option to uninstall it.  Posting these comments is getting pointless, update your question to explain *exactly* what you did with the VB6 project.

Comment: I suggest renaming any of your classes that share names with ADO at least as a diagnostic. If the error still exists after the rename then that wasn't the problem.

Comment: No need to remove ADO or rename anything. Just use the fully qualified object name when declaring the variable in VB, e.g. `Dim fld As MyInterface.Field`. There are lots of COM objects concurrently used, where properties/methods share the same name. If you're unsure what the right VB name is, hit F2 (Object Explorer) and see how VB references it.

Comment: @HelO'Ween That's a good idea, I tried it just to verify that it wasn't the issue.  I'm unfortunately still getting the same error.  It's such a confusing error, it lilterally is "Unable to cast object of type 'MyInterface.Field' to type 'MyInterface.Field'."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was simple.
I changed the code to expect an "object" on Append and found that the vb6 error code was more specific.  It was having issues with where the code originated from.  From there all i did was make the project (compile it into an executable) and everything worked as it should, no exceptions, nothing.

The solution, as it often seems to be, is not to depend on the vb6 IDE when dealing with odd errors.